# Difference in behaviour in Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.2 in converting rdd[row] to rdd[tuple]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So my code in Spark 1.6 works fine whereas the same code is giving a null pointer exception while running in Spark 2.2
I am currently running everything in local via IntelliJ:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("HbaseSpark")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("spark.hbase.host", "localhost")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "\001")
  .load("/Users/11130/small")

val df1 = df.withColumn("row_key", concat(col("C3"), lit("_"), col("C5"), lit("_"), col("C0")))
df1.registerTempTable("mytable")

val newDf = sqlContext.sql("Select row_key, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7," +
  "C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19 from mytable")

val rdd = newDf.rdd

val finalRdd = rdd.map(row => (row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2).toString, row(3).toString, row(4).toString, row(5).toString, row(6).toString,
  row(7).toString, row(8).toString, row(9).toString, row(10).toString, row(11).toString, row(12).toString, row(13).toString,
  row(14).toString, row(15).toString, row(16).toString, row(17).toString, row(18).toString, row(19).toString, row(20).toString))


finalRdd.toHBaseTable("mytable")
  .toColumns("event_id", "device_id", "uidx", "session_id", "server_ts", "client_ts", "event_type", "data_set_name",
    "screen_name", "card_type", "widget_item_whom", "widget_whom", "widget_v_position", "widget_item0_h_position",
    "publisher_tag", "utm_medium", "utm_source", "utmCampaign", "referrer_url", "notificationClass")
  .inColumnFamily("mycf")
  .save()
```

Whereas, the same code when I write in Spark2.2 gives null pointer exception in converting rdd to finalRdd

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("FunnelSpark")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.hbase.host", "localhost")
  .getOrCreate

val sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hbase.host", "localhost")

val df = spark
  .read
  .option("delimiter", "\001")
  .csv("/Users/11130/small")

val df1 = df.withColumn("row_key", concat(col("_c3"), lit("_"), col("_c5"), lit("_"), col("_c0")))
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")

val newDf = spark.sql("Select row_key, _c0, _c1, _c2, _c3, _c4, _c5, _c6, _c7," +
  "_c8, _c9, _c10, _c11, _c12, _c13, _c14, _c15, _c16, _c17, _c18, _c19 from mytable")

val rdd = newDf.rdd
val finalRdd = rdd.map(row => (row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2).toString, row(3).toString, row(4).toString, row(5).toString, row(6).toString,
  row(7).toString, row(8).toString, row(9).toString, row(10).toString, row(11).toString, row(12).toString, row(13).toString,
  row(14).toString, row(15).toString, row(16).toString, row(17).toString, row(18).toString, row(19).toString, row(20).toString))

println(finalRdd.first())
spark.stop()
```

Stacktrace: https://jpst.it/15srX

Comment: Why are you using RDD at all in Spark2?

Comment: @cricket_007 I need to write something to HBase as part of a POC and most of the solutions I could come up with are rdd based.

Comment: Okay, well, can you add your stacktrace?

Comment: @cricket_007 https://jpst.it/15srX
Stacktrace

Comment: Are you able to successfully show or `head` the Dataframe?

Comment: Also, first result for Spark Hbase I get uses Dataframes https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/master/README.md#write-to-hbase-table-to-populate-data

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I am able to show the dataframe newDf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you code is extremely unsafe. When you call:

```
row(i).toString
```

it is bound to throw NPE every time you encounter `null` value.

You should use:

```
row.getString(i)
```

Your 1.6 program uses different source than 2.2 and `spark-csv` is similar, but not the same as built in `csv` format. The first one considers empty strings as empty strings, the second one as `nulls`.